# jenkins job unable to read Service fabric registry Keys

Tags: azure, powershell, jenkins, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to setup jenkins job to create service fabric cluster locally using powershell script DevClusterSetup.ps1[By default available in setup directory] file. The script is working perfectly when runnin through local powershell. Biut when i am runnins same script it is unable to read registry keys of service fabric. When i am trying with other registry keys its working. only with service fabric reg keys its not working.

```
 Get-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Service Fabric SDK' because it does not exist.
```

At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\DevClusterSetup.ps1:61 char:20

Where as service fabric sdk is already installed in my system.

Comment: Did you install SF SDK in the machine where the build agent is running? The SDK setup create these keys, if the key is not in there, probably the setup failed.

Comment: Yes I have installed service fabric ask and I can see key values in regedit

Comment: Is the Jenkins machine a full VM or container environment?